# Interacting with SVG elements using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, svg, this

I was able to add listen even to the squares, that alert 'this is my name' upon the click.

my question is:
Instead of just making the alert, I need to execute the `animate` function, so that each item start moving upon clicking it

```js
var NS="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";     
var SVG=function(h,w){
    var svg=document.createElementNS(NS,"svg");
    svg.width=w;
    svg.height=h;
return svg;
}
var svg=SVG(1200,1500);
document.body.appendChild(svg);


var rect=function(x,y,h,w,fill,name){
    var SVGObj= document.createElementNS(NS,"rect");
    SVGObj.x.baseVal.value=x;
    SVGObj.y.baseVal.value=y;
    SVGObj.width.baseVal.value=w;
    SVGObj.height.baseVal.value=h;
    SVGObj.setAttribute("height",h);
    SVGObj.style.fill=fill;
    SVGObj["my-name"] = name;
    SVGObj.name = name;
return SVGObj;
}


for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var x = Math.random() * 500,
        y = Math.random() * 300;
  
    var r= rect(x,y,10,10,'#'+Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16),'this is my name');
    r.addEventListener('click', ()=>alert(r.name));  // or r["my-name"]
    svg.appendChild(r);
}

var animate=function(obj){
    obj.x.baseVal.value+=1;
    obj.y.baseVal.value+=1;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @Maksyum and @Angelos, I found the below approach to work fine as will, so instead of using `e.target` I restructured my module to use `this`. I'll evaluate both options further before marking the most suitable one for my case, just liked to mention it here in case any one interested or have comments about this approach.

```js
var NS="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";     
var SVG=function(h,w){
    var svg=document.createElementNS(NS,"svg");
    svg.width=w;
    svg.height=h;
return svg;
}
var svg=SVG(1200,1500);
document.body.appendChild(svg);


function myRect(x,y,h,w,fill,name){
   this.name=name;
   this.SVGObj= document.createElementNS(NS,"rect");
   this.SVGObj.x.baseVal.value=x;
   this.SVGObj.y.baseVal.value=y;
   this.SVGObj.width.baseVal.value=w;
   this.SVGObj.height.baseVal.value=h;
   this.SVGObj.style.fill=fill;
   this.SVGObj.addEventListener("click",this,false);
   this.handleEvent= function(evt){
      switch (evt.type){
        case "click":
          //  alert(this.name); // this.animate();
          var move = setInterval(()=>this.animate(),100);
        break;
      }
    }
/* Use either this.animate or myRect.prototype.animate for the animation, As I prefer using the prototype function the `this` method here is inactive
    this.animate=function(){
       this.SVGObj.x.baseVal.value+=1;
       this.SVGObj.y.baseVal.value+=1;
 }
*/
return this.SVGObj;
}

myRect.prototype.animate = function() {
   this.SVGObj.x.baseVal.value+=1;
   this.SVGObj.y.baseVal.value+=1;
};

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var x = Math.random() * 500,
        y = Math.random() * 300;
  
    var r= new myRect(x,y,10,10,'#'+Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16),'this is my name');
    svg.appendChild(r);
}
```

**UPDATE**
I found the same can be obtained using JavaScript Class as presented in ES6 (ECMAScript 2015), below is the full code using class:

```js
var NS="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";     
var SVG=function(h,w){
    var svg=document.createElementNS(NS,"svg");
    svg.width=w;
    svg.height=h;
return svg;
}
var svg=SVG(1200,1500);
document.body.appendChild(svg);

class myRect {
  constructor(x,y,h,w,fill,name) {
   this.name=name;
   this.SVGObj= document.createElementNS(NS,"rect");
   self = this.SVGObj;
      self.x.baseVal.value=x;
      self.y.baseVal.value=y;
      self.width.baseVal.value=w;
      self.height.baseVal.value=h;
      self.style.fill=fill;
      self.addEventListener("click",this,false);
  }

/* Use either get or Object.defineProperty of a prototype to make the getter / return of the shape/node, As i prefer using the prototype function the `get` method here is inactive
 
  get node() {
    return this.SVGObj;
  }
*/
}

Object.defineProperty(myRect.prototype, "node", {
get: function() {
    return this.SVGObj;
}
/* you can use this for making setter also if required, like below
,
  set: function(value) {
  name = value;
}
*/
});

/* OR another way to define getter / setter using Object property:
var pattern = {
get: function () {
    return this.SVGObj;
},
set: function () {
    name = value;
}
};

Object.defineProperty(myRect.prototype, 'node', pattern);  // myRect.prototype === this
*/

myRect.prototype.handleEvent= function(evt){
self = this.SVGObj;
  switch (evt.type){
    case "click":
       // alert(this.name); // this.animate();    
       if (typeof self.moving == 'undefined' || self.moving == false) self.moving = true;
       else self.moving = false;
 
     if(self.moving == true)
       self.move = setInterval(()=>this.animate(),100);
       else{
       clearInterval(self.move); 
       self.parentNode.removeChild(self);
       }        
    break;
    default:
    break;
 }
}  

myRect.prototype.step = function(x,y) {
   return svg.createSVGTransformFromMatrix(svg.createSVGMatrix().translate(x,y));
}

myRect.prototype.animate = function() {
       self = this.SVGObj;
              self.transform.baseVal.appendItem(this.step(1,1));
   // Or the below can be used instead of the custom function `step`
   //    self.x.baseVal.value+=1;
   //    self.y.baseVal.value+=1;
};

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var x = Math.random() * 500,
        y = Math.random() * 300;
  
    var r= new myRect(x,y,10,10,'#'+Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16),'this is my name');
    svg.appendChild(r.node);
}
```

Comment: I support your decision to restructure your model, as this is a better practice as far as object-oriented programming goes. If you found any answers helpful, please upvote them! Have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 1):

To make this work properly you should pass the event to the callback function and then use `event.target` to get the element which was clicked.

The reason your initial code was not working is that you passed the `r` variable which is not enclosed to any function scope thus by the time you actually click the rectangle `r` always equals the last added element.
To avoid this in the future you should read about [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)  and [hoisting](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp)

```js
var NS="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";     
var SVG=function(h,w){
    var svg=document.createElementNS(NS,"svg");
    svg.width=w;
    svg.height=h;
return svg;
}
var svg=SVG(1200,1500);
document.body.appendChild(svg);


var rect=function(x,y,h,w,fill,name){
    var SVGObj= document.createElementNS(NS,"rect");
    SVGObj.x.baseVal.value=x;
    SVGObj.y.baseVal.value=y;
    SVGObj.width.baseVal.value=w;
    SVGObj.height.baseVal.value=h;
    SVGObj.setAttribute("height",h);
    SVGObj.style.fill=fill;
    SVGObj["my-name"] = name;
    SVGObj.name = name;
return SVGObj;
}


for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var x = Math.random() * 500,
        y = Math.random() * 300;
  
    var r= rect(x,y,10,10,'#'+Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16),'this is my name');
    r.addEventListener('click', (e)=>animate(e));  // or r["my-name"]
    svg.appendChild(r);
}
var animate=function(e){
    e.target.x.baseVal.value+=1;
    e.target.y.baseVal.value+=1;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call `animate(e.target)` inside the `r.addEventListener('click',(e)=>...)` as shown below. You should pass `e.target` as an argument to the function otherwise you will pass the event itself and the event does not have `x` and `y` properties.

```js
var NS="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";     
var SVG=function(h,w){
    var svg=document.createElementNS(NS,"svg");
    svg.width=w;
    svg.height=h;
return svg;
}
var svg=SVG(1200,1500);
document.body.appendChild(svg);


var rect=function(x,y,h,w,fill,name){
    var SVGObj= document.createElementNS(NS,"rect");
    SVGObj.x.baseVal.value=x;
    SVGObj.y.baseVal.value=y;
    SVGObj.width.baseVal.value=w;
    SVGObj.height.baseVal.value=h;
    SVGObj.setAttribute("height",h);
    SVGObj.style.fill=fill;
    SVGObj["my-name"] = name;
    SVGObj.name = name;
return SVGObj;
}


for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var x = Math.random() * 500,
        y = Math.random() * 300;
  
    var r= rect(x,y,10,10,'#'+Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16),'this is my name');
    r.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      console.log(e.target.name);
      console.log(e.target.x.baseVal.value);
      animate(e.target); // Pass the event's target as argument
      console.log(e.target.x.baseVal.value);
    });  
    svg.appendChild(r);
}
var animate=function(obj){
    obj.x.baseVal.value+=1;
    obj.y.baseVal.value+=1;
 }
```

I also added some `console.log()` statements to show the result of animating the object as the 1px move is sometimes difficult to see:

Comment: This solution will not work because `r` will always refer to the last element created. You can actually see it when your snippet works.

Comment: @MaksymStepanenko you are right, I will update it! - **EDIT:** Updated, it works properly now!

Comment: Thanks @AngelosChalaris for the answer and its correction. now it works fine.